# How to read .xcresult file to generate report

Tags: testing, kif

Can someone please help me to understand if there is a way I can read .xcresult file generated by executing KIF test from command prompt ? I want to read it outside of xcode to generate some reports from it. 
Thanks
Samir

Answer (score 2):

I use xcparse and xcresulttool to parse the results to JSON. 
You can install both via home-brew or equivalent using

```
$ brew install chargepoint/xcparse/xcparse
```

Gathering all the screenshots of an xcresult

```
$ xcparse screenshots --test <path-to-.xcresult> <destination_path>
```

Here is where I found the way : https://www.chargepoint.com/engineering/xcparse/